# What is the cardinality?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $A=\left\{1,2,\cdots,10\right\}$

Let $f,g:A\to A$. Consider the **equivalence relation**

$$ fRg \iff \exists h:A\to A. f=h\circ g$$ where $h$ is invertible.

Now, let $g(x)=5$:

Why is $\left| \left\{ f\in A\to A : fRg \right\} \right| = 1$?

**Update:**
If $f(x) = 5$ then it's true that $f = h\circ g$ if $h$ is the identity function.
Now, Why any other function won't work?

Comment: That is not an equivalence relation. Call it relation anyways. And I think that you swished the order of the relation, so it should be fRg inside the set, maybe? And try to find any f in the set.

Comment: Sorry, I added another condition: $h$ is invertible.

Comment: I corrected it to $fRg$ but anyway, it's symmetric (because $R$ is an equivalence relation).

Comment: So I think that the answer is ten, any constant function would suit the requirements

Comment: You have the relevant permutation that switches 5 with f(2), for example, to set g = h o f.

aybe the relation is defined by exists h s.t. f= g o h? If then it is really trivial since if f = g o h, then im f \contained im g = { 5 }

Comment: If $gRf$, then $f=h∘g$. With $g$ the *constant* function mapping $A$ in $5$, we have that $f(x) = h[g(x)] = h(5)$; thus we have no other possibility than the *constant* function $f$ which maps $A$ into the single value $h(5)$.

Comment: That would held 10 different functions, one for each possible value of $h$. :/

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, the final answer is $1$, whereas you're saying $h$ may be any invertible function.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, your interpetation is correct. So why is the cardinality equals $1$?

Comment: Well, maybe there's a mistake/typo in my book. idk

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you are defining the relation by $f\sim g \Rightarrow \exists h | f = g \circ h$.

If so, take a  $f = g \circ h$, then $im f \subseteq im g = \{ 5 \} $ so clearly $f$ would be the constant function with value $5$, hence $f=g$.

Comment: No, $f~g \iff f = h\circ g$

Comment: So you saw Mauro's answer, it's not 1, it's 10.